# optimizing C code with imbedded for loops

Tags: c, optimization, conways-game-of-life

```
    void evolve(board prv, board nxt){
      
       int i, j;
       int n;
    
       printf("\rGeneration %d\n", generation++);
       if (printLazy == 1){
         lazyPrint(prv);
       
for (j=0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
          for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
             n = neighbors(prv, i, j);
             if (prv[i][j] && (n == 3 || n == 2))
                nxt[i][j] = true;
             else if (!prv[i][j] && (n == 3)) 
                nxt[i][j] = true;
             else
                nxt[i][j] = false;
          }
       }
    }
```

** Some asked me to add the neighbors method so

```
static int neighbors (board b, int i, int j) {
   int n = 0;
   int i_left = max(0,i-1);
   int i_right  = min(HEIGHT, i+2);
   int j_left = max(0,j-1);
   int j_right  = min(WIDTH, j+2);
   int ii, jj;

   for (ii = i_left; ii < i_right; ++ii) {
      for (jj = j_left; jj < j_right; ++jj) {
         n += b[ii][jj];
      }
   }

   return n - b[i][j];
}
```

So I am working on optimizing this so that it will go faster and I'm stuck on how to optimize this more. Here's what I have so far

```
void evolve(board prv, board nxt) {
  
   register int i, j;
   int n;
   bool next;

   printf("\rGeneration %d\n", generation++);
   if (printLazy == 1){
     lazyPrint(prv);
   }
   
   for (j=0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
      for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
         n = neighbors(prv, i, j);
         if (prv[i][j])
                if (n == 2)
                        next = true;
                else if (n == 3)
                        next = true;
                else
                        next = false;
         else
                if(n == 3)
                        next = true;
                else
                        next = false;
         nxt[i][j] = next;
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this or are there any resources or videos y'all recommend?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Compile with optimizations enabled.  That will most likely be better than anything you do by hand.

Comment: I wonder if switching the loop (to have major axis first) nesting would enable better data locality .. I’m also a fan of using temporary variables, for ‘reading simplicity’ through reduced repeated expressions if nothing else.

Comment: you complicated second loop with adding extra statement in the loop. for optimization you must decrease *statements in the loop* and *number of iterations*.

Comment: Describe algorithm or provide `prev` and `help` for more help.

Comment: You optimize since you presumably care about performance, yet you don’t measure performance, ergo you don’t care about it. See the problem? Make an optimized release build, run it under something like VTune or cachegrind, and see if what you “improve” actually improves stuff.

Comment: http://downloads.gamedev.net/pdf/gpbb/gpbb17.pdf

Comment: Post definition of `neighbors()` for better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas Inline your function `neighbors()`. Or turn it into a macro. Tidy up the conditional. To unroll the inner loop replace every use of `i` with the literal values so your code looks like :

```
for (j =0;.......
   n = fun(prev, 0 ,j);
   If.....
      n = fun(prev, 1, j);
   if......
```

and so on.
If the value of HEIGHT was let's say 100, then you get a code explosion of 100 function calls and 100 compound conditionals. Even worse if you unroll the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` was limited to say 8 neighbors, use a lookup table

```
bool foo[2][8] = { [1][2] = true,  [1][3] = true, [0][3] = true };

for (j=0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
  for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    n = neighbors(prv, i, j);
    nxt[i][j] = foo[prv[i][j]][n];
  }
}
```

---

A common weakness is the `neighbors(prv, i, j)` function itself.  One trick to to oversize the 2D array by 1 on all four sides and populate the edge with `false` so `neighbors()` can always check 8 neighbors as it is never used on the edge/corners.

Making sure the 2nd dimension is a power of 2 helps also - simplifies index calculation.  So if the original array way `12*11`, make the new array `(1+12+1)*(1+11+1+4)` or `14*16`.

Comment: @0x476f72616e I suspect so, yet OP has provided scant details.  As usual with such posts  "how to speed up code" focuses on a minor linear issue rather than reducing O().